# valums ajax fileupload and rails response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload

I am using valums file upload. I am not sure how to render the response when the file is successfully uploaded.

Below is my controller code.

```
def upload
    return if params[:qqfile].blank?
    @doc = Document.new
    @doc.data  params[:qqfile].read
    @doc.filename = params[:qqfile].original_filename

    if @doc.save
      render :text => '{success:true}'
    else
      render :text => 'Faild.'
    end
end
```

my erb looks like this.

```
<script language="javascript">
function createUploader(){
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file1'),
        action: '<%= url_for({:controller => :documents, :action => :upload}) %>',
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
            }
    });           
}
window.onload = createUploader;
</script>
```

My question is How do I render a partial (which displays uploaded doc details and has a view delete link) on successful upload of doc. Please help.

I am using Rails 2.3.8 and [Valums File upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)